# Dimension of a weight space which is of weight $0$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a module of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $V_{0}$ be the weight space of $V$ of weight $0$.
$$
V_0 = \{ v\in V: h.v = 0, h \in \mathfrak{h} \},
$$
$\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

It is said that $\dim V_0 = 1$. How to prove this? Thank you very much.

Edit: Let $V$ be a highest weight module of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with the highest weight $0$. Is it true that $\dim V = 1$? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is false without further assumptions on $V$.  Even if $V$ is irreducible it is still wrong, e.g. the adjoint rep of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ has zero weight space of dimension two, spanned by the CSA.

Comment: @mt_, what assumptions do we need ($V$ is finite dimensional?)? Thank you very much.

Comment: More typically the zero weight has the highest multiplicity in an irreducible module (of highest weight in the root lattice, for otherwise the multiplicity is zero). This does hold for irreducible modules of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ of an even highest weight, and, of course, for the 1-dimensional trivial representation.

Comment: An irreducible module of highest weight $\lambda$ always has 1-dimensional weight space $V_\lambda$. May be whoever made this claim meant that?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you very much. I edited the post. Let $V$ be a highest weight module of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with the highest weight $0$. Is it true that $\dim V = 1$?

Comment: @LJR: If $V$ is a highest weight module with highest weight $0$, then every weight is $0$. So if $V$ is irreducible, it has dimension $1$. If $V$ is not irreducible, then in general I think $V$ will be infinite-dimensional

Comment: @spin, thank you very much.